# Use regex to print contents from text file

Tags: python, regex

I have file that is in the format

```text
file = "chapter 1

what is your name 

chapter 2 

where do you live

chapter 3

what is your qualification
```

I need to print it into multiple files using regex, 
File 1 should have:

```text
chapter 1
what is your name
```

File 2:

```text
chapter 2 
where do you live
```

File 3:

```text
chapter 3
what is your qualification
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you have already read the entire text file into Python, you may use `re.findall` here:

```py
file = """chapter 1
what is your name
chapter 2
where do you live
chapter 3
what is your qualification"""
chapters = re.findall(r'\bchapter \d+.*?(?=\s+\bchapter \d+|$)', file, flags=re.DOTALL)
print(chapters)
```

This prints:

```
['chapter 1\nwhat is your name', 'chapter 2\nwhere do you live',
 'chapter 3\nwhat is your qualification']
```

Comment: in this case it would print all into one file.. i need to find first chapter and below content of that chap into one file and so on. please help

Comment: Each entry in my output list is one chapter.  Are you unable to iterate the list and write a new file for each chapter?